# how to write data attributes in UML with typedef unsigned

Tags: c++, uml, class-diagram

this is my sample code my question is how am i going to write `uint delay` in UML Class Diagram, because it is `typedef unsigned` -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------should i write it like this? `- delay : int` or this way? `- delay : uint` ---------------------------------------

```
typedef unsigned int uint; 

class MyBreakoutGameType : ...
{
public:

private:
     uint delay;
};
```

Comment: What's that strange formatting about? Did you want o show a UML diagram? Hint: You can model `typedef`s in UML as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your diagram for the mentioned code should look like

[image]

Comment: The stereotype «typedef» is not defined in UML. The dependency arrow is redundant.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Stereotypes can be defined as you like, e.g. with language specific profiles.

Comment: That is right. Your answer should include the remark that your diagram is only valid if UML has been extended by a profile that defines the «typedef» stereotype. You might also mention the way a profile can be defined in UML using the «profile» and «stereotype» stereotypes (for an example, see figure 12.14 on page 257 of the UML 2.5 spec).

Comment: A little late to this party, but don't you loose the information on the underlying type? The diagram does not unveil that `uint` is actually an `unsigned int` (despite the name strongly suggesting it...)

Answer (score 2):

UML has a few predefined primitive types, e.g. "Integer", but "int" is not a predefined primitive type in UML. New primitive types can be modeled using a classifier with the «primitive» keyword (UML 2.5 spec, section 10.2.5). To specify the corresponding C++ data type, you may wish to add a note:

[image]

Then, you may using this primitive data type as the data type of an attribute, like this:

[image]

Of course, this makes the class dependent on the existence of the «primitive» uint. You may stress this dependency by drawing a dashed arrow from MyBreakoutGameType to uint, but this is optional.

Answer (score 2):

Version 13.5 of Enterprise Architect does import `typedef`s as classes with `«typedef»` stereotype. The original type is then referred to by generalization. This way the information of the underlying type does not get lost.

[image: typedefs with stereotype]

In case the `«typedef»` stereotype is undefined (and shall not be added to the used profile) you may use an ordinary class which has an `«import»` relation to the original type.

[image: typedefs by import]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46720133/5534993) suggests to use only the `«import»` relation specifying the name of the alias on the connector. I do not prefer that solution as the alias can then not be referred to.

Comment: Version 13.5 of Enterprise Architect does import `using` type aliases as classes with «alias» stereotype.